# É possível compartilhar as informações de auto name count no TFS?

Tags: versionamento, team-foundation-server

Estou usando o Enterprise Architect integrado com o TFS para gerenciar o versionamento e possibilitar que mais de uma pessoa trabelhe com a solução. 
Não conseguimos compartilhar as configurações de auto name count entre os diferentes usuários. É possível fazer isso?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Edite a pergunta, somos uma comunidade que usa o idioma Portugues amigo.

Comment: Valeu, nem tinha percebido que era o StackOverflow Br

Comment: Só faltou o titulo :)

Comment: Pronto, agora que vi....

Comment: Isto é um software que você está tentando usar?

Comment: Sim. O Enterprise Architect permite fazer a modelagem de classes, estrutura de banco de dados, diagrama de caso de usos, requisitos, sequência, etc.......
Depois tem como configurar ele pra gerar template de documentação e até de código

Answer (score 0):

Você quer versionar o documento do EA e que o número varie conforme o que no TFS? O changeset?
O que eu entendo desse processo é: você tem um documento que vai ser versionado no TFS, não sei se dá para integrar com o TFS o incremento do número da versão, por que isso não é um build, que é quando o TFS incrementa a versão dos binários gerados. O melhor seria você deixar que o incremento seja pelo EA, por que é um documento e não codigo. 
Dica: não coloque esse documento no TFS! Sim, é um contra senso, mas o repositório de código não é o melhor lugar para versionar documentos. O melhor seria você colocar no Sharepoint do time que é associado ao projeto.

Comment: O controle do versionamento é realizado dentro do próprio EA (check in, check out,...) que utiliza a estrutura do TFS pra isso.
Esse contador que me refiro não é o changeset do TFS e sim um contador do próprio EA que utilizamos pra gerar os elementos internos. Exemplo: Fiz uma configuração de auto naming para casos de uso dizendo que ele Utilizará o prefixo UC e o contador é 001. Quando eu adiciono um novo caso de uso ele já gera o nome automaticamente UC002. Ao adicionar o próximo terei o UC003 e assim por diante.
Essa configuração de auto name count é que não consigo compartilhar.